# Building unit tests for asp.net mvc2 async controller actions that return data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asynchronous

I've had a good look around and I can't seem a specific answer to the above question. For example, this thread:

[Building unit tests for MVC2 AsyncControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968892/building-unit-tests-for-mvc2-asynccontrollers)

talks about waiting for async actions to finish, which is great, but I then need to be able to retrieve the data returned from the Completed method.

Cheers, Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to do this is make the event handler:

```
controller.AsyncManager.Finished += (sender, ev) => {
                                                  var result = controller.TransactionCompleted();
                                                  trigger.Set();
                                                }
```